# Tango power up intermittent. Now nothing

Tags: google-project-tango

I set my tango down for a couple of months while busy with other things. I charged it for a bit, turned it on and saw the red battery icon. I charged it overnight and saw the green battery symbol. I clicked the power button The splash screen came up, said it was installing updates and screen turned off. That evening I tried to turn it on and it wouldn't do anything. Next morning it turned on - splash screen - white screen, off. Now it doesn't do anything at all. I've tried - volume button and power, both volume buttons...nothing.  Has anyone else had this problem? Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On the below instruction. it only diagnose your device for hardware and BSP level problem. Tango Core and Apps related is not included.

To diagnose your device problem. First we need reset your device.

---

1. Hard Reset device
   Press your device power key for around 8-10 secs.
   sometimes you will see the backlight of screen is off.
2. Diagnose what is going on on your tango devices

   2.1 Check basic bootloader function.

   Plug in device with a charging usb cables.

   2.1.1 if your device is out of power.
       It will show red battery icon. or green icon which you device still enough battery to boot it up.

   2.1.2 if your device is not any icon pop up. 
   Try 1 step again. or
   switch different Usb cables and chargers or charging docks.

   If it still doesn't work.It is possible a hardware issues now.  you may need to contact project-tango-help@google.com

   2.1.3 if you do see the battery icon, but without charging icon on it.
   That mean something wrong with your charging cable or devices. Switch different charger and cables. if problem still exists. you may need to contact project-tango-help@google.com

   2.2 Check the Software side of the devices
     if you can see the icon in 2.1.1, that is good.
     Normally on Green icon, you can boot up your device.

   2.2.1 after the icon is gone, press the power key are 1-3 secs, device will boot up. 
      you will see the tango icon and the rolling tango icon as part of booting process.
      if you get stuck at this two process forever. it means that there is some problem on booting image on android.  please go to section 2.3.

   if you can see the Android UI without problem. you are fine.keep a eye on your battery. if it show 50% on charging full. and some weird condition. you may need to contact project-tango-help@google.com for more details.

   2.3 Recovery your device by android recovery mode.
   if you android system can't boot up successfully, Recovery your device is needed. Remember it will wipe out all your data,and cache. so try to backup your data if possible.

   2.3.1 If you device can access by ADB, try : adb reboot recovery
   or try below steps:

   {  make sure device is off,
    press the power key with volume Up and Down key at the same time for around 2-3 seconds, till you see Bootloader menus

   you will see

   ```
          {
           Continue

           Fastboot protocol

           Recovery mode

           Reboot

           Power off

           Force Recovery
          }
   ```

   by using volume Up and Down, and power key you can select the item.
   select "Recovery mode"

2.3.2: now you are at Tango android recovery mode.
it will show

`reboot system now
 apply update from ADB
 wipe data/factory reset
 wipe cache partition`

Using Volume down key for moving, and power key for selecting.
The same step as normal Android recovery step.
  1. wipe cache partition
  2. wipe data/factory reset
then select reboot system now.
Waiting device to boot up.

2.3.3, If your device is still not good. Google didn't provide the tango image for customer fastbooting the device. you had to contact project-tango-help@google.com for next step.